# How to add data from another class to JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a Gadget, Mobile, MP3 and GadgetShop class. The Gadget is the super class, the Mobile and MP3 are Subclasses of the Superclass and the GadgetShop is the GUI I made.

I just need my GadgetShop to gather the information to place it in the TextFields I've made when I click the button I've made. I have no idea how to pass the information.

I'm using BlueJ by the way.

**This is my Mobile Class:**

```
/**Mobile phone class that:
 * allows calling credit to be applied that is more than 0
 * shows remaining calling credit
 * allows a phone number to be added
 * shows duration of phone call 
 */
public class Mobile extends Gadget
{
    private int credit;
    private int duration;
    private String number = "";

    /**
    * Constructor for objects of class Mobile.
    */
    public Mobile(double ThePrice, int TheWeight, String TheModel, String TheSize) 
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        super(ThePrice, TheWeight, TheModel, TheSize);
    }


    /**
    * Insert the duration of the call.
    */
    public void insertDuration(int length)
    {
        System.out.println("A duration of " + length + " minutes for the phone call has been inserted!");
        duration = length;
    }

    /**
    * Insert the phone number.
    */
    public void insertNumber(String numberAdder)
    {
        System.out.println("The phone number " + numberAdder + " has been inserted!");
        number = numberAdder;
    }

    /**
    * Insert credit for the call.
    * A positive amount will need to be added in order for successfull credit to be applied,
    * otherwise an error message is displayed.
    */   
    public void insertCredit(int calls)
    {
        if(calls > 0) {
            System.out.println("Successfully added " + calls + " pounds of credit!");
            credit = credit + calls;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You need to insert a positive amount more than " + credit + " pounds.");
    }
    }

    /**
    * Make the phone call.
    * If the credit is equal to or more than the duration, a message displays the phone number and duration of the call.
    * If the credit is 0, a message will be displayed to insert more than 0.
    * The number of minutes the call lasted is reduced by the amount that was available.
    */
    public void makePhoneCall()
    {
        if(credit == 0)
        System.out.println("Insert more than 0 credit to make a phone call!");
    else {
        if(credit >= duration) {
        System.out.println("The phone number " + number + " has been dialed and is being called for " + duration + " minutes");
        credit = credit - duration;
        duration = 0;
    }
    else {
        if(credit < duration)
        System.out.println("You do not have enough credit to make a phone call! Your credit is " + credit + " pounds");
    }
    }
    }

    public void mobilePrint()
    /**
    * Print the details of the mobile.
    **/
    {
       System.out.println("The price of the mobile is " + price + " pounds"); 
       System.out.println("The weight is " + weight + " grams");
       System.out.println("The model is " + model); 
       System.out.println("The size is " + size);
    }
}
```

**This is my GadgetShop:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GadgetShop implements ActionListener
{
    private JTextField model, price, weight, size, credit, memory, phoneNo, duration, download, displayNumber;
    private JButton addMobile, addMP3, clear, displayAll;

    //These JTextField's are for the labels
    private JTextField model2, price2, weight2, size2, credit2, memory2, phoneNo2, duration2, download2, displayNumber2;

    private JFrame frame;
    private ArrayList<Gadget> gadgetDetails;

    public GadgetShop()
    {
        makeFrame();
    }

    public void addGadget(Gadget newGadget)
    {
        ArrayList<Gadget> GadgetList = new ArrayList<Gadget>();
        Gadget Object = new Gadget(1.00,20,"model","big");
        GadgetList.add(Object);
        model.setText("hi");
    }

    public void makeFrame()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Gadget Shop");
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();

        model = new JTextField(10);
        price = new JTextField(10);
        weight = new JTextField(10);
        size = new JTextField(10);
        credit = new JTextField(10);
        memory = new JTextField(10);
        phoneNo = new JTextField(10);
        duration = new JTextField(10);
        download = new JTextField(10);
        displayNumber = new JTextField(10);

        //Display Model text box and model info    
        model2 = new JTextField("Model:");        
        contentPane.add(model2);
        model2.setOpaque(false);         
        contentPane.add(model);  

        price2 = new JTextField("Price:");
        contentPane.add(price2);
        price2.setOpaque(false);
        contentPane.add(price);

        weight2 = new JTextField("Weight:");
        contentPane.add(weight2);
        weight2.setOpaque(false);
        contentPane.add(weight);

        size2 = new JTextField("Size:");
        contentPane.add(size2);
        size2.setOpaque(false);
        contentPane.add(size);

        credit2 = new JTextField("Credit:");
        contentPane.add(credit2);
        credit2.setOpaque(false);
        contentPane.add(credit);

        memory2 = new JTextField("Memory:");
        contentPane.add(memory2);
        memory2.setOpaque(false);
        contentPane.add(memory);

        phoneNo2 = new JTextField("Phone Number:");
        contentPane.add(phoneNo2);
        phoneNo2.setOpaque(false);
        contentPane.add(phoneNo);

        duration2 = new JTextField("Duration:");
        contentPane.add(duration2);
        duration2.setOpaque(false);
        contentPane.add(duration);       

        download2 = new JTextField("Download:");
        contentPane.add(download2);
        download2.setOpaque(false);
        contentPane.add(download);

        displayNumber2 = new JTextField("Display Number:");
        contentPane.add(displayNumber2);
        displayNumber2.setOpaque(false);
        contentPane.add(displayNumber);

        addMobile = new JButton("Add Mobile Number");
        contentPane.add(addMobile);
        addMobile.addActionListener(this);

        addMP3 = new JButton("Add MP3 Song");
        contentPane.add(addMP3);
        addMP3.addActionListener(this);

        clear = new JButton("Clear");
        contentPane.add(clear);
        clear.addActionListener(this);

        displayAll = new JButton("Display All");
        contentPane.add(displayAll);
        displayAll.addActionListener(this);

        contentPane.setLayout (new GridLayout(4,4));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        String command = event.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals("Add Mobile Number")) {
            addMobile();
        }  
    }

    public void addMobile()
    {
        model.setText("");
    }


    public void clearText()
    {
        model.setText("");
        price.setText("");
        weight.setText("");
        size.setText("");
        credit.setText("");
        memory.setText("");
        phoneNo.setText("");
        duration.setText("");
        download.setText("");
        displayNumber.setText("");
    }
}
```

Where I have the:

```
public void addMobile()
{
    model.setText("");
}
```

I want to add the details of the Mobile Phone

Comment: There's no need to call `setOpaque(false)` in every `JTextField`. The `actionPerformed` should be `if(event.getSource().equals(addMobile) { //Your code here }`... But, even then, I'm still not sure what's your problem. For better help sooner post a valid [mcve], 2 `JTextField` are enough to demonstrate your GUI, a MCVE is not a code snippet or your whole code, but a small, runnable example that includes a `main` method and your imports and we can copy-paste, compile and run w/o modifications on our part to see your issue

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of you names are correct. Some are not. Be consistent!!!

Comment: @Frakcool Isn't the setOpaque to remove the background so is needed in them all? And why can't the actionPerformed be that if it works fine when I use a String of text to be in the JTextField as a test?

Comment: @Bob my bad, I got confused, I thought you were trying to make them opaque... I think it's better to compare against an object than against a String, because you could fail at writing the command right (I mean a typo), just as a suggestion

Comment: @Frakcool Yes, and all I want to know is how to get the information from my Mobile class, so when it has the information, my button called 'ADD MOBILE' will display the details it contains. How do I do that?

Comment: As said in the answer below: mobile.getCredit(); or something like that for example

Answer (score 1):

Similarly how you do it in the `addGadget` method you could add a `Mobile` parameter to `addMobile`

```
public void addMobile(Mobile mobile)
{
    // You should add getter methods for attribute 
    //in the Mobile class to get meaningful values here instead of toString
    model.setText(mobile.toString()); 
}
```